# Robocopy -- skip specific file types?

Tags: robocopy

I went through Robocopy's documentation here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy

Couldn't figure it out since no examples.

Is there a way to set robocopy so that it skips specific file types (e.g. PDFs)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the command reference `/xf *.pdf` should work, see [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy#file-selection-options) for details.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks!